Dual cone of the strictly nef cone
Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. It's known that the nef cone is dual to the pseudo-effective cone, which is the closure of the effective cone.
A divisor is called nef if it has non-negative intersection with every curves, and a divisor is called strictly nef if it has positive intersection with every curves. It's known that there exists a strictly nef divisor which is not ample by Hartshorne's example, so the strictly nef cone is properly bounded between the ample cone and the nef cone.
I'm wondering is there any results about the structures or descriptions of strictly nef cone and its dual cone?

There are various results about strictly nef divisors, for example you can see the recent paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00208-022-02461-1 which mentions some of them. About the dual: according to the usual definitions, a cone and its closure have the same dual cone. So the dual of the strictly nef cone is the same as the dual of the nef cone.
